# XML Start and End Tags

Tags: xml, tags

I need to display the Name of the Start tag and the end tag at appropriate positions while parsing an xml file. I have to use other method than using startElement and endElement functions. Below is an example as how I expect my output to be.

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<Employee-Detail>
<Employee>
  <Emp_Id>E-001</Emp_Id>
  <Emp_Name>
  <First_Name>Mani</First_Name>
  <Last_Name>Maran</Last_Name>
  </Emp_Name>
  <Emp_E-mail>Vinod1@yahoo.com</Emp_E-mail> 
  </Employee>
</Employee-Detail>
`
```

Output:
StartTag:Employee-Detail
StartTag:Employee
StartTag:Emp_Id
Value:E-001
EndTag:Emp_Id
StartTag:Emp_Name
StartTag:First_Name
Value:Mani
EndTag:First_Name
StartTag:Last_Name
Value:Maran
EndTag:Last_Name
EndTag:Emp_Name
StartTag:Emp_E-mail
Value:Vinod1@yahoo.com
EndTag:Emp_E-mail
EndTag:Employee
EndTag:Employee-Detail

Comment: ?  I have no clue what you are asking.. ?

Comment: I need to parse the xml document and in the console have to print the tags along with the values correspondingly (The position of start tag and end tag should be as in the xml) without using the startElement and endElement methods.

Comment: Not using a particular method (or two) is a bizarre requirement (there might be a reason for it, but that reason needs to be explained so any alternative solution can avoid whatever problem those methods introduce). That said, those methods don't exist in the context of the question. What code have you got so far. What programming language are you using? Why do you need to output this particular data structure (the XML is perfectly good)?

Answer (score -1):

using SAX parser will allow you to parse XML line by line and emit output that you wanted

Comment: can you please post an example ?